# JSON e múltiplas linhas

Tags: json

Estou construindo um arquivo `JSON` onde pretendo adicionar várias linhas, como é mostrado no código exemplificado abaixo:

```
[  
   {  
      "Numero":"0001",
      "Textos":[  
         {  
            "letra":"Meu Jesus maravilhoso és,
                    minha inspiração a prosseguir,
                    e mesmo quando tudo não vai bem
                    eu continuo olhando para ti...",       
            "titulo":"Aos pés da cruz"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Porém, fazendo dessa forma, sempre recebo a mensagem de caracteres inválidos.
Pelo que pesquisei, o `JSON` não suporta o recurso para uso de várias linhas. Ainda assim existe alguma forma de criar o modelo relatado no código acima?

Comment: Em que linguagem de programação está tentando? Poderia postar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível, conheço duas opções para fazer isso, a primeira seria usar um array de palavras:

```
[  
   {  
      "Numero":"0001",
      "Textos":[  
         {  
            "letra": [
                       "Meu Jesus maravilhoso és,",
                       "minha inspiração a prosseguir,",
                       "e mesmo quando tudo não vai bem,",
                       "eu continuo olhando para ti..."       
                     ],
             "titulo":"Aos pés da cruz"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

A solução acima interpreta multiplas linhas na hora da montagem.

Já de acordo com o padrão especificado você pode usar os seguintes valores para o tipo *char*:

- `\"` - aspa dupla
- `\\` - caractere de escape
- `\/` - barra
- `\b` - decrementa o ponteiro do cursor em um caracter
- `\f` - quebra de página
- `\n` - quebra de linha
- `\r` - decrementa o ponteiro do cursor em uma linha
- `\t` - quebra de parágrafo
- `\u` - quatro digitos hexadecimal

Então você pode usar o `\n` no final de cada linha para que isso seja interpretado tal como:

```
[  
   {  
      "Numero":"0001",
      "Textos":[  
         {  
            "letra":"Meu Jesus maravilhoso és, \n minha inspiração a prosseguir, \n e mesmo quando tudo não vai bem \n eu continuo olhando para ti...",       
            "titulo":"Aos pés da cruz"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

---

Referências:

[Especificação do JSON (Inglês)](http://json.org/)

[How to code long JSON value strings as multiline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077104/how-to-code-long-json-value-strings-as-multiline)